# Method overloading in descendent classes in Typescript

Tags: typescript

What I have in mind is pretty simple:

```
class A {
    getSomething(name: string): number {
        return 1;
    }

 }

class B extends A {
    getSomething(n: number, name: string): number {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

A method defined in one class should get overloaded with an additional parameter in a descendent class. In reality the method in class B will detour to A depending on the new parameter. However, I get the error:

> Class 'B' incorrectly extends base class 'A'.   Types of property
>   'getSomething' are incompatible.
>       Type '(n: number, name: string) => number' is not assignable to type '(name: string) => number'.

See this code in [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getSomething(name%3A%20string)%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getSomething(n%3A%20number%2C%20name%3A%20string)%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%202%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D). What would be the correct approach here? Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could explicitly declare the overloaded function signatures:

```
class A {
    getSomething(name: string): number {
        return 1;
    }

 }

class B extends A {
    getSomething(name: string): number;
    getSomething(n: number, name: string): number;

    getSomething(n, name?) {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

With the above you override the original function too. It is your responsibility to call the superclasses function when the parameters are given that way. An example:

```
class A {
    getSomething(name: string): number {
        return 1;
    }
 }

class B extends A {
    getSomething(name: string): number;
    getSomething(n: number, name: string): number;

    getSomething(n: any, name?: any): any {
        if (typeof name !== "string") { 
            return super.getSomething(n);
        } 
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does compile but not work. `getSomething("blah")` will also end up in B then (and return 2), however it should use the implementation in A (and return 1). Otherwise we get function hiding, not overloading.

Comment: @MikeLischke That's the intended behavior. This is how overloading works in TypeScript. You have multiple signatures but a single implementation, it's the implementors responsibility to provide the right types for the right inputs. This is inherited from JavaScript.

Comment: Oh, then it's named wrongly I'd say. Need to find a different approach then. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MikeLischke You are kind of right. I updated the answer with some code that might help you here. Otherwise you will have to use a different function name.

Comment: Yes, nice idea, but not feasible (no implict any allowed). A different name is probably my only choice.

Comment: Just for the record: You can use explicit any :)